# I don't have a recovery key and my password doesn't work since using Migration Assistant

Tags: time-machine, password, recovery, migration

I have a new Macbook pro (same model/spec) and I have today used Migration Assistant from a Time Machine Backup.

It took 20 hours to complete the transfer but once it had completed I was logged into my old user account on the new MBP.

On first load it started asking for my admin password and would not accept it.

I restart the Macbook and now my login doesn't work.

The only option I have to reset passwords from both the login screen and recovery mode (CMD + R on boot) is to enter this elusive recovery key which I was never given.

To make the situation more confusing, i've tried to generate a recovery key on my old MBP and that generates a 28 length recovery key but the new MBPs recovery key is only a 24 length input.

I am exhausted of options of how to get the newer MBP to a state where I can do anything other than enter a recovery key or guess my password which has seemingly changed somehow.

I am scared to log out or turn off this old Macbook pro incase it suffers the same fate.

What can I do here?

EDIT -

I have just logged into appleid.apple.com and it is showing "Recovery Key Not Set Up"

Comment: Did you Migrate as part of the initial setup, or afterwards, once you had set a new account on the new mac?

Comment: What model MBP? Did you erase the disk and install macOS before using migration assistant? We need the precise order and what you did.

Comment: I did not erase the disk before using the Migration Assistant. I used Migration assistant once the new MBP had booted up for the first time. I created a new account when prompted to and then proceeded to use Migration Assistant

Comment: Then I think you may have ended up with two accounts, a new one [that you didn't really need] & the old one, which was what you migrated. I once did this accidentally & trying to stitch the two back together into useful form took me several days. Honestly, it would be far simpler to just wipe the new Mac, start afresh & do the Migrate as part of the initial setup, without making a new account - that way the 'old' account just becomes the 'new' account, with everything intact from before, all data/keychain etc should then carry over correctly. Check whether you do see 2 accounts if you logout.